# Slice's State self reference inside reducer

Tags: redux, immer.js, redux-toolkit

When updating my state inside a slice's reducer with the redux's toolkit, I ran into the problem of the circular reference, for example:

```
const aSlice = createSlice({
...
extraReducers: builder => {
    ...,
    builder.addCase(addToState.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.data = {
            ...state.data,
            ...action.payload.data
        };
    });
    ...,
  }

});
```

Thus resulting in `...state.data` returning a proxy reference instead of the value which is one of the pitfalls mention, [Redux Toolkit doc](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation) as well as in [Immer.js pitfalls section](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/pitfalls).

I can think of some ways to hack this into working but, I was wondering if they were any best practice for this matter or any elegant way of making this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using Immer and proxies, a useful pattern for "assign all" is to actually use `Object.assign()`.

Typically, use of `Object.assign()` with Redux involves passing an empty object as the first parameter to make it an immutable update, like `Object.assign({}, oldItem, newItem)`.

However, with Immer, you can do a truly mutating update to assign all incoming properties to the existing object.  In this case, `Object.assign(state.data, action.payload.data)`.